# Events triggered by controls but passed to owner list<>

Tags: c#, list, events

I want to find out how to forward events raised from a class to the owner class which implements the List<> that the class raising the event is contained in.  The main class is called `PCCControls` and contains a `List<ControlBox>` objects. Each `ControlBox` implements an event called `ButtonPushed`.

I want to move the event from the `ControlBox` class to the `PCCControls` class by implementing an event in the `PCCControls` class similar to:

```
public delegate ControlBoxButtonPushedHandler(object sender, ControlBox controlbox);
public event ControlBoxButtonPushedHandler ButtonPushed;
```

I have the following:

```
public class PCCControls
{
    List<ControlBox> ControlBoxes;
}  

public class ControlBox
{
    public event ButtonPushed;  

    public ProcessSub()
    {
        if(ButtonPushed != null) ButtonPushed(this, new EventArgs());
    }
}
```

So based on the code above, I would like to move the event `ButtonPushed` from the `ControlBox` class to the `PCCControls` class and just pass the `ControlBox` in which the event was fired as a parameter to the `ButtonPushed` event.

How is this achievable?  Your support will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear what you are asking; but, I'll take a stab.  You can simply get the `PCCControls` class to subscribe to events in a `ControlBox`:

```
public class PCCControls
{
    List<ControlBox> ControlBoxes;
// initialization of ControlBoxes done elsewhere...
    public voice SomeMethod()
    {
        ControlBoxes.ElementAt(0).ButtonPushed += controlBox_ButtonPushed;
    }
    public void controlBox_ButtonPushed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO:
    }
}
```

If that's not what you looking for, please provide more detail.

Answer (score 0):

If you make sure the actual list remains private to the PCCControls class (so client code can not directly add/remove ControlBoxes to/from it), you can subscribe/unsubscribe from the ControlBox's ButtonPushed event when an item is added or removed, and then define your own event to forward it to client code. Something like this:

```
public class PCCControls
{
    public event EventHandler<PCCButtonPushedEventArgs> PCCButtonPushed;

    List<ControlBox> ControlBoxes;

    public void AddControlBox(ControlBox box) 
    {
        box.ButtonPushed += OnButtonPushed;
        ControlBoxes.Add(box);
    }
    public void RemoveControlBox(ControlBox box) 
    {
        box.ButtonPushed -= OnButtonPushed;
        ControlBoxes.Remove(box);
    }
    private void OnButtonPushed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var handler = PCCButtonPushed;
        if (handler != null) 
        {
           var box = (ControlBox)sender;
           handler(this, new PCCButtonPushedEventArgs(box));
        }
    }
}  

public class ControlBox
{
    public event ButtonPushed;  
    public ProcessSub()
    {
        if(ButtonPushed != null) ButtonPushed(this, new EventArgs());
    }
}
```